# Losing Build History after Upgrade to Jenkins

Tags: jenkins

I've upgraded Jenkins twice but each time I had to rollback as we lost the build history.

The first time I did it automatically through GUI --> Manage Jenkins --> Upgrade Automatically

The second time I downloaded the MSI through the website:
https://jenkins.io/content/thank-you-downloading-windows-installer/

And LTS and 2.7.1WAR-- Windows

Perhaps there is an upgrade path I have to follow. I'm currently on version 1.543.

I also see other people you can just drop the WAR file into a specific path.

Any thoughts?

Regards,
David